# Do all representations of finite groups have one-dimensional subrepresentations?

Tags: representation-theory, finite-groups

Let V be a representation of a finite group G, and $v\in V$ - a nonzero vector. Put $$u = \sum_{g\in G} gv.$$
Then for any $g\in G$ we have $gu = u$ and therefore $<u>$ is a subrepresentation of V.

I know there is an error here since there are irreducible representations of finite groups which are not one dimensional, but I can't see it. Could someone point it out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible that $u$ is zero.

Comment: @Artem, You could have found this out by yourself by picking *any* irreducible representation of dimesion larger than one of *any* group! You should *always* look at examples.